# Build workflow in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was wondering if there is a way to streamline the "build workflow" (not sure how to better name it) in ASP.NET Core 2.0.

If I have some code in a controller or some DB access code that I need to change, is the workflow "change the code, build the project, refresh the browser"? Or, is there some kind of way to make a change and have Visual Studio recompile the code on the background and refresh the browser automatically? Kind of like what WebPack does for TypeScript/HTML/CSS.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: you are looking for `dotnet watch`

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to refresh Chrome automatically?

Comment: There is [BrowserLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-browserlink?tabs=aspnetcore2x) for that